# toolbar in ASP.NET web application: singleton approach always returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using toolbar in master page as user control.

While initializing the toolbar through a singleton approach (see below), `GetInstance()` always returns null toolbar.

Code:

```
Toolbar uc = (BaseClass.GetInstance()).toolBar;

public class BaseClass
{
    private static BaseClass instance;
    public Toolbar toolBar;

    public static BaseClass GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new BaseClass();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Why does `GetInstance()` always return a null toolbar?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: GetInstance() always returns null toolbar.

Comment: Please formulate your question as an actual question, or state what you want to accomplish.

Comment: The Toolbar never gets assigned in your code example. When would that happen?

Comment: Did you mean to say should I give you a complete background?

Comment: Toolbar toolBar = (BaseClass.GetInstance()).toolBar; //this line always gets null

Comment: Clarify the question.

Comment: Actually I have a User Control(Toolbar) in Master Page and I am changing buttons in toolbar on page load event of the page. So I am using singleton approach to do the work but I am failed in it. However same singleton approach logic is working in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you ever use `Toolbar` is here `public Toolbar toolBar;`. At this point you have declared a variable of type `Toolbar`, but have not initialized it in any way. Hence its value is `null`

So, when you get an instance of your BaseClass and then access the `toolbar` property in that instance you access a null value and that is what you are getting out of it. However you initialize that Toolbar is up to you, but you have to initialize it in someway to not get a null value back.

Comment: Sir I have used it in Silverlight and it is working fine while in Asp.net it always gets null

Answer (score 0):

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHM5z.jpg)

I think this picture can elaborate that what I want to achive

Answer (score 0):

You do not instantiate an object for your toolbar public field. It does not matter from where you have lifted the code or how you instantiate. If it is not instantiated when you call it (and it is a reference type) you will get null back. Clearly you fail to do this for some reason.

Below is your code adjusted to illustrate a way of fixing it. But if you inject an instance into your singleton externally then you have to make sure your code can handle if it comes back null..

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private static BaseClass instance;
    public Toolbar toolBar;

    public static BaseClass GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new BaseClass();
            instance.toolBar = new Toolbar(); // or however you instantiate toolbar.
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

There are multiple things bothering me with the code snippet you provide (for example your singleton not being threadsafe and your exposing the toolbar field directly), but above is likely why your code does not work..